# Select Drop down in angular application using protractor

Tags: angular, protractor

I want to select a value from dropdown using index. I am a beginner in protractor, and got stuck with selecting dropdown.  This is the DOM for couple of dropdowns and I have pasted my protractor code below the DOM

```
<ng-dropdown-panel class="ng-dropdown-panel ng-select-bottom" 
    ng-reflect- klass="ng-dropdown-panel" 
    ng-reflect-items="[object Object],[object Object]"
    ng-reflect-position="auto" ng-reflect-buffer-amount="4" 
    ng-reflect-virtual- scroll="false" id="a5a3c1993a27" style="opacity: 1;">

    <div class="ng-dropdown-panel-items scroll-host">
        <div></div>
        <div>
            <div class="ng-option" role="option" id="a93a68b7b452">
                <span class="ng-option-label">Scholar1</span>
            </div>
            <div class="ng-option" role="option" id="aa1cf5337c38">
                <span class="ng-option-label">Scholar2</span>
            </div>
            <div class="ng-option" role="option" id="a36388ede7a3">
                <span class="ng-option-label">Scholar3</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-dropdown-panel>
```

I tried the following Protractor code, the test did not fail and did not perform any selection.In the code , I have given index 2, to select the 3rd value in drop down.  Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
exports.selectDropdownByNumber = function (element, index, milliseconds) 
{
    element.findElements(by.className('ng-dropdown-panel ng-select-bottom'))
        .then(function (options) {
            options[2].click();
        });

    if (typeof milliseconds != 'undefined') {
        browser.sleep(5000);
    }
};
```

Thanks
K

Answer (score 1):

You should find the dropdown options: `<div class="ng-option">`, rather than the options container: `<ng-dropdown-panel class="ng-dropdown-panel ng-select-bottom"`

```
exports.selectDropdownByNumber = function (element, index, milliseconds) 
{
    element.findElements(by.css('ng-dropdown-panel.ng-select-bottom .ng-option'))
        .then(function (options) {
            options[2].click();
        });

    if (typeof milliseconds != 'undefined') {
        browser.sleep(5000);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Yong, but unfortunately the above code did not work .

Comment: before call above function, you need to click on the dropdown to make it expand the options to be visible.  You can choose to wrap the click in this function or call the click outside this function.